# how to change the title of an image upload to a name in a class in django

Tags: python, django, class, model, attributes

I know this has been asked a couple of times, but I am new to django and couldn't find that in the documentation or here. I want to upload images to a class and the name should have the same name as the name of the class.

models:

```
import os 

def upload_to_company(instance, filename):
    blocks = filename.split('.')
    ext = blocks[-1]
    filename = "%s.%s" % (Cars.name, ext)
    instance.title = blocks[0]
    return os.path.join('media/', filename)

    class Cars(models.Model):
        image_file = models.ImageField(upload_to=upload_to_company, null=True, blank=True)
        name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
```

How do I get the name of the cars class? I thought `Cars.name` will do it but it doesn't.

Can anyone help?

Thanks !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

to get the class' name use

```
Cars.__name__
```

If you go through an object (e.g. `camaro = Cars()`), use

```
camaro.__class__.__name__
```

In case you want to name of the image to depend on one of the other model attributes (e.g. `name`)

```
def upload_to_company(instance, filename):
    if hasattr(instance, 'imgpath'):
        if os.path.exists(instance.imgpath):
            os.remove(instance.imgpath)
    blocks = filename.split('.')
    ext = blocks[-1]
    filename = "%s.%s" % (instance.name, ext)
    instance.title = blocks[0]
    instance.imgpath = os.path.join('media', filename)
    return instance.imgpath
```

Note: that will always replace the existing file.

And finally, get your indentation right: the `Cars` class appears to be defined within the `upload_to_company` function.

Comment: Thanks! but now i get the class name, like CARS and not the brand that the user types in? So the user has a category names cars. He adds a category with name camero and then the picture he uploads should get that name?

Comment: please explain what you intend to do. Your question was quite clear and it was about the class. If you now want the car model, then you should act differently

Comment: Sorry, I think I misformualted my question. Exactly I want the car models name, so I want the value of the name attribute of the car class

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/84408/discussion-between-pynchia-and-klaus-ruprecht).

Comment: Hi, what do I do when I want the old image to be deleted? I only want one image per car to be saved

Comment: Thank you! However, it doesnt delete the previouse loaded picture